# Get current object in function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, object, uitextfield

I'm trying to code a simple UITextField and I have a simple question:
Im using this to 'empty' the UITextField:

```
-(IBAction)editbegin{
campo1.text="";
```

}

The problem is: want to use this function in more than one TextField. So, how can I 'grab' the object, so I can get the 'text'? Already tried 'self.text', but it returns the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the UITextField documentation. It looks like you are trying to "reinvent" the wheel.

If all you want to do is clear the textfield once a user begins editing, there is a function for that.

When creating your text field, just set:

```
textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
```

The same option is also available on Interface Builder if that's what you are using.

Specific documentation link here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearsOnBeginEditing

Comment: Im using Interface Builder, but i could find the damn option to clear this thing ._.

Answer (score 1):

Include the "sender" property.

```
-(IBAction)editbegin:(id)sender{
   sender.text=@"";
}
```

Edit: Apparently you need to cast it? I thought you could send any message to id. I guess this is better code, anyway.

```
-(IBAction)editbegin:(id)sender{
   UITextField *field = (UITextField *)sender;
   field.text=@"";
}
```

Comment: Now, im getting "Property 'text' not found on object of type 'id'. Sorry, im starting to code object-c today, still a lot to learn :S

Comment: Is the element that is triggering the editBegin action a UITextField? Or a UIButton?

Comment: Cast the id to (UITextField*).

Comment: Is a UITextField. Already tried to change 'id' to 'UITextField*', but when I select the field, I get a crash (green selected line)

Comment: @markus see the other answer, may do exactly what you want in an easier way.